# Try MongoDB or stick to MySQL

Tags: mysql, mongodb, doctrine, database, nosql

I am coding a web portal which stores a lot user data and later on maybe documents. In the meantime I use MySQL with many relations. I have read much about NoSQL and find that it is an interesting topic.

Is MongoDB or CouchDB ready to fully replace MySQL? Would something change in the usage of Doctrine in my application?

Comment: This is a bit dated but it may help you rephrase your question: http://blog.nahurst.com/visual-guide-to-nosql-systems.  Basically, what are you planning on doing that may entail changing databases?  You can store the absolute filename in mysql so document storage isn't a big deal.  Which one is best depends on needs.

Comment: 'Is MongoDB or CouchDB ready to fully replace MySQL' - it _can_ do, but there will always be a demand for relational databases. So in some cases, sticking with a RDMS is the best option. Whilst this question may be closed for being too discursive, you could outline what sort of loads you're dealing with (number of tables, number of rows, queries per second, joins per query etc). My guess is that you may be scaling too early.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is MongoDB or CouchDB ready to fully replace MySQL?

Sure, lots of people are storing their entire data set in MongoDB instead of MySQL and they are doing fine.

But I do not think that is the correct question. The key questions are really the following:

- Does implementing MongoDB improve your system? Less queries, more flexibility, better performance?
- Are you capable of implementing MongoDB at the appropriate scale?

MongoDB is a tool like many others and it does not solve all problems. In my experience, most systems are best implemented with some mix of databases. That would means something like MongoDB for *some* data and SQL for *other* data.

Comment: Thank you for your answers!
So I would say the conclusion is to take the way what fits best and don't try to force new technologies, just to have them :)